# The image of bounded linear operator is closed iff the image of its subspace is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Banach space $E$ is the direct sum of its closed subspaces $L$ and $M$. $M$ is finite dimensional. $T:E \rightarrow E$ is a bounded linear operator. I'm asked to prove that $T(E)$ is closed iff $T(L)$ is closed.

I have only learned the open mapping theorem and closed graph theorem, and have no idea how to prove that the image is closed. Any hint will help. Thank you.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237009/an-operator-has-closed-range-if-and-only-if-the-image-of-some-closed-subspace-of